# Line_interpolate_point: 2nd arg isnt within [0,1] in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, interpolation

Im trying to interpolate a point on edge using ST_LineInterpolatePoint but it is giving an error saying that **Line_interpolate_point: 2nd arg isnt within [0,1]**'

```
create table interpolate as (
select coalesce(
        case 
        when abb.node=edg1.start_id
        then ST_LineInterpolatePoint(st_makeline(st_linemerge(edg1.geom)), (300-abb.cost)/edg1.travel_spped :: double precision)
        else ST_LineInterpolatePoint(st_makeline(st_linemerge(edg1.geom)),((300-abb.cost)/edg1.travel_spped) :: double precision)

        END,
        abb.geom
        )as geom from  abb left join hyd_network as edg1 
        on abb.node in (edg1.start_id,edg1.end_id) 
AND edg1.gid not in (select edge from abb) group by abb.node,edg1.start_id,abb.cost,edg1.travel_spped,abb.geom  )
```

But if i replace 2n argument with any value between 0,1 like `ST_LineInterpolatePoint(st_makeline(st_linemerge(edg1.geom)), 0.3)` it is giving result as expected. In my code the 2nd  argument also giving value between 0,1 but it is not taking.

Comment: I still suspect that your code does not give value within correct range.

Comment: Please tell me how to resolve !

Comment: Double check what `(300-abb.cost)/edg1.travel_spped` gives you.

Comment: Its correct only.

Answer (score 2):

Without the context of your [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572251/how-to-get-a-road-path-which-can-be-travelled-in-10-minutes-from-a-location/51686168) *and* the untested, original (but already updated/changed, tested and working) query I gave as an answer (check the edit logs), the above part by itself doesn´t have a problem.
The issue arises in combination with the result set of the `pgr_drivingDistance` function; my inital solution only works if the

```
... AND edg1.id NOT IN (SELECT edge FROM abd) ...
```

part filters out *all* edges that were already fully traversed. Since, and here was my mistake, the function's result set does not contain *all* edge `ids`, but only those traversed to reach the end nodes, some of the inner edges will be processed by the above subquery; if then `(300 - abd.cost)` of a falsely processed edge happens (which is to be expected) to be larger than `travel_speed`, the result is `> 1`, which leads to that error.
Also, it seems you added some overhead and unnecessary groupings to the query, which would, in the end, break the whole process again.
The updated query does not only solve this, but returns all fully traversed edges *and* the fractions of those that can only be traversed partially 'in time', as *LineStrings* with reference to the respective edge `id`.
You might want to avoid cross posting of questions and/or their context in the future ,) I only happened to read this, and I doubt, without the context, there would be a chance to answer this properly.

Answer (score 0):

fitting a value into a range like [0,1] is called [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling). It's commonly used in statistics. Here, because it doesn't make sense to let you to find a point that isn't on the line.

You need to find the maximum and minimum data values, after that you can scale values to the range using

```
x' = x - min(x) / (max(x)-min(x))
```

Your current expression doesn't look as if it will guarantee that. Also the if and else clauses appear identical (apart from extra brackets),  not sure why?

Comment: Its not fitting anything here, In postgis ST_LineInterpolatePoint takes two arguments. first argument will be edge or a line and second argument will be a fraction (float8) that should  be in between 0 to 1.